# Accessing the last element of a variable in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

I have a set:

> Set t /t1*t6/;

Let us consider there is a variable called var. I have a constraint that the last element of var is less than 20.

> Variable var(t);
>
> Equation const;
>
> const..
>
> var('t6') < 20;

I would like to replace 't6' in the last line by something like card(t), so that if the size of t changes then I do not have to change it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dollar condition to limit the equation to the last period:

```
const(t)$(ord(t) = card(t)).. var(t) < 20;
```

Or you could define a singleton subset for your end condition like so:

```
singleton set tEnd(t) /t6/;

const.. var(tEnd) < 20;
```

Comment: Just ran into this one by chance. The proposed solution is actually wrong. $(card(t)) is true for every t. This was probably meant to be $(ord(t)=card(t)).

Comment: Oops, good catch! I have edited the answer accordingly. Goes to show that I as a dayly GAMS user can get by without ever touching ord or card (mostly relying on .val)

Comment: Note that the syntax in the second example is actually wrong now... :) You have the data statement /t6/ as part of the assignment now.

Answer (score 2):

You could also define an upper bound with the help of the "last" attribute of the set t:

```
Set t /t1*t6/;

Variable var(t);

var.up(t)$(t.last) = 20;
```

Best, 
Lutz